# Is there an equivalent to Stack Overflow for community related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I feel like there are a lot of questions to do with software development that aren't necessarily coding related, things like:

- > Can someone explain to me where the JEE applet servers and the idea of running multiple apps on the same server came from?
- > What are some interesting architectures besides x86-64 that are supported by gcc and making a comeback?
- > What are some easy to get into mailing lists related to OS projects centered around this language/domain?

I feel like these kinds of questions are be in a sense programmer-related since a programmer is best suited to answer them, but don't really fit Stack Overflow. Is there a website in the SE network that's dedicated to such questions? Or any plans to build a new "branch" of SO that deals with this type of stuff?

Comment: We don't really do list questions. So the last two are unlikely to fly anywhere round here.

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You should post them on Programmers.SE ... *runs!*

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain to me where the JEE applet servers and the idea of running multiple apps on the same server came from?

This deals with the objective history of programming, but there isn't really any site that's especially welcoming to programming-history questions. It's not exactly practical enough for SO, but Software Engineering might take it. (They do have [a tag for the purpose](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), with recent, highly-upvoted, open questions, and no recent closed questions.)

On the other hand, "running multiple apps on the same server" doesn't actually sound all that interesting a mental leap, so you might get downvoted just because the idea was obvious at the time Java was developing.

> What are some interesting architectures besides x86-64 that are supported by gcc and making a comeback?

Not a terribly great question as phrased: it shouldn't be difficult to find out for yourself what architectures gcc supports, then work out which of those you find "interesting". (And if you did want to ask this you would need to do this to avoid downvotes.) The meat of the question is really "which of this list of architectures is making a comeback", but that's fairly opinion-based. It *may* be possible to find reliable research on the subject, but it's not real likely.

This would likely go on Software Engineering, if anywhere.

> What are some easy to get into mailing lists related to OS projects centered around this language/domain?

Yeah, no, this is **not** going to work on any SE site. We do not do recommendation-list questions for things like mailing lists. (Or indeed *anything* except on special sites dedicated to that purpose, such as Software Recs, Hardware Recs, etc. There is no "Online Group Recs" site, and there almost certainly never will be.)